# duality in linear programming for cost minimization of forest plantations

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems, operations-research

I am trying to use duality in linear programming to minimise the cost for highest possible revenue. Forest plantations have 2 species (pine and eucalyptus), i have 3 cost variables (land,labour and capital) and the overall revenue for each specie. is this a possible match for duality ? how can i then build this and solve it using GAMS or excel ?

Comment: How does the duality comes into play here? Isn´t it just a ordinary linear program which has to be solved?

Comment: My line of reasoning was that the primal problem was maximization of revenue/profit and the  dual problem being cost minimization thus being an issue of duality. would you say its an ordinary linear program and not one of duality ?

Comment: Yes, dual  problems  are ordinary (linear) problems. To get an appropriate answer you should post the specific problem.

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com